# Handling selected/unselected states with ImageView as Tab indicators

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm using ImageViews for my Tab indicators in a TabActivity. I have two copies of the same jpeg file, one scaled to 75% of the original. What I want to be able to do is use the normal size for selected and the smaller for unselected.

StateListDrawable doesn't work with ImageView so I figure I have to handle this myself. All I can find that seems to relate to tab selection changing is `TabHost.onTabChanged(String tabId)` - I assume the tabId is the String I passed to `new TabSpec(...)`.

Is this the only way to track tab changes? It would be useful to have an event handler (or handlers) to allow the previously selected tab to change view state and then the new tab to do the same. I can maintain a variable such as `int currentSelection` but it would be useful if it could be a bit more automated.

Comment: "StateListDrawable doesn't work with ImageView" -- sure it does.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I get a ClassCastException when I try using ImageView's setImageDrawable() when I use an XML file defining the 'selector' for a StateListDrawable. I've run around in circles with that one and couldn't solve it. Any links to sample code you can point me at?

Comment: Use `setImageResource()`, not `setImageDrawable()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Ah! Thank you. That's possibly the only thing I didn't try last night as I slowly drove myself nuts trying to solve it. First attempt at a TabActivity but I'll remember that one in future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** My ideal approach was to use StateListDrawables with my ImageViews but I was getting a ClassCastException when attempting to use ImageView.setImageDrawable() with xml files defining the state images.

The answer is to use setImageResource() instead, it works perfectly for what I need. Thanks to CommonsWare for pointing me in the right direction.